# jade mixin, conditional leave out

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, pug

I'm trying to make a Jade mixin. I want it to omit stuff if I did not input a variable. Maybe it's easier to explain if I show what I mean in code

```
mixin movie-left-image(title, posterUrl, venue, rating, 3d)
    article
        h2
            strong= title
        div
            div                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                img(src = posterUrl)
                div
                    img(src = venue)
                    img(src = rating)
                    img(src = 3d)
```

Not all of the info is known, nor will be available when I use the mixin. So instead of making amillion mixins, like one for when a movie has no rating, or one for when a movie is not available in 3d, I'd like to make just one to cover all these bases.

In this case, say I leave out 3d, I want Jade to ignore 3D at output. But I don't understand how to make Jade ignore 3d if I leave it out. Or any of the other fields, like venue or rating. As in, is it like a null value, or do I have to put everyone of the ones affected in if statements?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a conditional to not input some code you don't want, in the case your variable is not specified.

```
mixin movie-left-image(title, posterUrl, venue, rating, 3d)
    article
        h2
            strong= title
        div
            div
                img(src = posterUrl)
                div
                    img(src = venue)

                    //- Use conditionals to check the presence of the variable
                    if rating
                      img(src = rating)
                    if 3d
                      img(src = 3d)
```

Comment: I was able to use this same pattern with attributes as well `attributes.target`. Thanks!